# Scrapy with a nested array

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy, nested

I'm new to scrapy and would like to understand how to scrape on object for output into nested JSON.  Right now, I'm producing JSON that looks like

```
[
{'a' : 1, 
'b' : '2',
'c' : 3},
]
```

And I'd like it more like this:

```
[
{ 'a' : '1',
'_junk' : [
     'b' : 2,
     'c' : 3]},
]
```

---where I put some stuff in `_junk` subfields to post-process later.

The current code under the parser definition file in my `scrapername.py` is...

```
item['a'] = x
item['b'] = y
item['c'] = z
```

And it seemed like

```
item['a'] = x
item['_junk']['b'] = y
item['_junk']['c'] = z
```

---might fix that, but I'm getting an error about the `_junk` key:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/item.py", line 49, in __getitem__
    return self._values[key]
exceptions.KeyError: '_junk'
```

Does this mean I need to change my `items.py` somehow?  Currently I have:

```
class Website(Item):
    a = Field()
    _junk = Field()
    b = Field()
    c = Field()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create the junk dictionary before storing items in it.

```
item['a'] = x
item['_junk'] = {}
item['_junk']['b'] = y
item['_junk']['c'] = z
```