# An array field in scrapy.Item

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to add a field to scrapy.Item so that it's an array:

```
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    field1 = scrapy.Field()
    field2 = scrapy.Field()
    field3_array = ???
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 27):

You just create a filed

```
field3_array = scrapy.Field()
```

But while parsing the scraped items do like this

```
items['field3_array'] = []

items['field3_array'][0] ='one'
items['field3_array'][1] ='two'
```

in this way you can achieve this.

Have a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507651/scrapy-with-a-nested-array)

Comment: Will this create a dict or a list? From scrapy documentation of Field, I suspect dict. In that case, it would be less misleading with `items['field3_array'] = {}`.

Comment: For empty list `items['field3_array'][0] = ...` will inevitably give IndexError, you should use `append` to add items.